# boto3 dynamodb scan filter between datetime epoch in demicals

Tags: python-3.x, boto3, dynamodb-queries

I am trying to query the attribute timestamp which is in epoch, decimal format. The aim is to filter all items that exist in a day.

I have the query below, and also tried the `between` clause, but both gave me an empty return.

```
from boto3.dynamodb.conditions import Attr
from datetime import datetime
from decimal import Decimal

start = datetime(2020, 5, 25).strftime('%s')
end = datetime(2020, 5, 26).strftime('%s')
response = table.scan(
            FilterExpression = \
                Attr('timestamp').gte(Decimal(start)) & \
                Attr('timestamp').lt(Decimal(end))
            )
print(response)
```

However, I found that just using `gte` (greater than) OR `lt` (less than) separately return a proper response, which is perplexing why they can't work together. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

Swap the values of start and end date since start should be older as per your scan query

```
start = datetime(2020, 5, 25).strftime('%s')
end = datetime(2020, 5, 26).strftime('%s')
```

Comment: pardon the error, have amended it and the result still returns as an empty list